Plotting minima of a mutivariable function
Consider a function,
z (x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y.
For a range of x, I like to plot the minimum values of z.
Specifically, suppose, when x = 1, we get z(1,y) = 1 + y^2 + 3y.
And the function has a minimum at y=y_c=-3/2that is z_min(1)= z(1, -3/2) = -5/4.
This way, I like to plot all such z_min(x) in the range -10<=x<=10.
I am implementing it in the following way:
z = x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y;
dzdy = D[z, y];
soln = Solve[dzdy == 0, y];
yc = y /. soln[[1]];
zmin = z /. y -> yc;
Plot[zmin, {x, -10, 10}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style[Text["x"], 16], Style[Row[{Subscript["z", "min"], "(x) = z (x, ", Subscript["y","c"], "(x))"}], 16, Blue]},
   PlotStyle -> Blue]

I like to know if the coding can be written in an efficient and compact manner to obtain my desired plot. Does there exist dedicated built-in functions to plot such minima?

When the x is fixed, then we set {D[z, y] == 0, D[z, {y, 2}] >= 0} to get the local minimum.
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y;
min = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -40, 40}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, D[f[x, y], y] // Evaluate]}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0 // Evaluate], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Red}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
plot3D = 
  Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -40, 40}, Mesh -> None], min,
    PlotRange -> All, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
   BoxRatios -> 1];
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, f[x, y]}, {D[f[x, y], y] == 0, 
     D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] >= 0, -10 <= x <= 10}}, {x, y}];
plot2D = Region[Style[reg, Red], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1];
{plot3D, plot2D}



For the function f[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^2-3*x*y-x^2*y-x*y^2;

Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y - x^2*y - x*y^2;
reg3d = ParametricRegion[{{x, y, f[x, y]}, {D[f[x, y], y] == 0, 
     D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] >= 0, -10 <= x <= 10, -20 <= y <= 20}}, {x, 
    y}];
plot3d = 
  HighlightMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[reg3d, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-20, 20}, {-50, 50}}], {Style[0, None], 
    Style[1, Directive@{Thick, Red}]}, ViewPoint -> Front, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"];
plot = Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -20, 20}, Mesh -> None],
    plot3d, BoxRatios -> 1];
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, f[x, y]}, {D[f[x, y], y] == 0, 
     D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] >= 0, -10 <= x <= 10, -20 <= y <= 20}}, {x, 
    y}];
plot2D = 
  Region[Style[reg, Red], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-50, 50}}];
{plot, plot3d, plot2D}


f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y - x^2*y - x*y^2;
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate@D[f[x, y], y]], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] >= 0]], 
 PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-20, 20}, {-50, 50}}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 ViewPoint -> Front, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]


Thank you. In my MWE, I missed to consider taking the 2nd derivate positive.

Kindly recheck, when the x is fixed, the minima of z is at y == -((3 x)/2), isn't it? So, shouldn't it be sol = Reduce[{D[z, y] == 0, D[z, {y, 2}] >= 0}, {x, y}]?
For example, for x=1, your value should be -5/4 whereas ur code gives -5/9. Check my question and @ubpdqn's answer.

@raf You are right. The y is a variable when x is fixed.

Thanks for the update. Instead of specifying the condition of y == -((3 x)/2) in Plot3D, Can the code be made such that it is computed and used internally, like implementing the sol somehow?

Also, on the line Plot[x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y /. ToRules[sol], {x, -10, 10}], isn't it a bit redundant to state the function again instead of just calling by z? :)

Thanks for the updates.

Can you please look at this question too? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/305184/83038

z = x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y;
pt = {x, y, z} /. Minimize[{z, x == 1}, {x, y}][[2]];
Show[Plot3D[z, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], 
   InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}], Opacity[1], Red, 
   PointSize[0.04], Point[pt], Black, 
   Text[pt, pt, {-1, -2}, Background -> LightBlue]}]]


Update: based on comment
z = x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y;
min = Minimize[{z, x == a}, {x, y}][[2]];
p = {x, z} /. min
q = {x, y, z} /. min;
ParametricPlot[p, {a, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]
Show[Plot3D[z, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), 
  Mesh -> 20], ParametricPlot3D[q, {a, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]



The target is to obtain a 2D plot of z_min(x) vs x.

The way you have defined pt, I like to plot all z for different  values ofx in the range -10<=x<=10.

Thank you for the update

Can you please look at this question too? It's related to the same topic. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/305184/83038

If I understand your question correctly, you want to plot z against x where z[x,y] has a minimum for given x. This can be done by noting that the partial derivative of f[x,y] relative to y by keeping x fix  is zero. This will determine y: ymin. And with ymin we can define zmin[x] = z[x,ymin[x]]:
z[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 + 3*x*y;
ymin = y /. Solve[D[z[x, y], y] == 0, y][[1]];
zmin[x_] = z[x, ymin];
Plot[zmin[x], {x, -10, 10}]


Addendum
To create a 3D plot, you would create a 3D plot of z[x,y] and a parametric plot of {x,ymin,zmin[x]} and combine both using Show:
gr1 = Plot3D[z[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
gr2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, ymin, zmin[x]}, {x, -10, 10}];
Show[gr1, gr2]



Can you generate a 3D plot of it too with this method?

Also, it's not required for this function, it would be wise to check the condition of 2nd derivative to be positive too, right?

Simply take 'D[zmin[x],{x,2}]'  and ckeck if it is negative.

I understand that. But I wanted to understand how to add the extra condition into the definition of your ymin.

By the way, you wanted to consider partial derivative of f[x,y] relative to y is zero but in the code, you have taken it relative to x.

Sure it is a typo. I fixed it.

But for a given fixed x, to get the minima of z(x,y), the derivatives need to be taken w.r.t. to y. For example, for x=1, your zmin should be -5/4 whereas your code gives -5/9. Check my question and @ubpdqn's answer.

You are right, I screwed up, done in a hurry. fixed it

Thank you for the update.

Can you please look at this question too? It's related to the same topic. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/305184/83038
